# New FTP user on Cloud Server with WHM Installed -- "Failed to retrieve directory listing"

Tags: ftp, cpanel, whm, filezilla

I have a Rackspace Cloud server running CENTOS 7.1 that has WHM installed over it.

I am having trouble when logging into cpanel for a specific domain, creating an FTP user, and logging in.

When logging in I receive:

> Status:   Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
>
> Status:   Connected Status:   Retrieving directory listing... Command:    PWD
>
> Response: 257 "/" is your current location Command:   TYPE I
>
> Response: 200 TYPE is now 8-bit binary Command:   PASV Response:  227
>
> Entering Passive Mode (xxx,xxx,xxx,xx,xxx,xxx) Command:   MLSD
>
> Error:    Connection timed out after 20 seconds of inactivity
>
> Error:    Failed to retrieve directory listing

I am not really sure to turn as I am not sure what the issue is, so any questions or a point in the right direction will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

There is an issues with the Passive Port, To fix this issues you will have to enable Passive Port range on your server.

Open your **/etc/pure-ftpd.conf** file and enable following line.

```
PassivePortRange 30000 50000
```

Save the pure-ftpd.conf file and restart FTP service.

If you are using CSF firewall on your server then add above Passive port range in **TCP_IN** and **TCP_OUT** line of **/etc/csf/csf.conf**

```
TCP_IN = "20,21,22,25,53,80,110,143,443,465,587,993,995,2077,2078,2082,2083,2086,2087,2095,2096,30000:50000"

TCP_OUT = "20,21,22,25,37,43,53,80,110,113,443,587,873,2087,2089,2703,30000:50000"
```

Comment: I really appreciate the response and was really hoping this would work, but  I am getting the same response.  I enabled the mentioned line on pure-ftpd.conf and restarted FTP.  I also am not using CSF firewall, so the second part was not needed.

Comment: Please try to disabled IPtables on your server. " /etc/init.d/iptables stop "